# Retrieving Custom Button Property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, button, properties

I've created a custom button called TaskUIButton that inherits from UIButton. The only difference I have right now is a "va" property.

Here's the interface

```
// TaskUIButton.h
@interface TaskUIButton : UIButton 
{
NSString *va;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *va;
@end
```

And the implementation file

```
//TaskUIButton.m
@implementation TaskUIButton
@synthesize va;

@end
```

Now, I've got an action that I'm using which I want to use to set and retrieve the va property of a button (just for testing/experimentation of course).

Here is where the button action is

```
- (IBAction)setAndRetrieveVa:(id)sender{

TaskUIButton *imaButton = [TaskUIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
imaButton.va = @"please work";
NSLog(@"%@", imaButton.va);
}
```

Upon activating the setAndRetrieveVa: action, my app crashes with:

```
-[UIRoundedRectButton setVa:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3a5a0
```

I'm sure that its a stupid mistake on my part, but I've been going at it for a while and would love some insight!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this because `buttonWithType:` is returning a new object which is a `UIRoundedRectButton` object which is a subclass of `UIButton`. You can't alter this behavior of the method unless you override but you are unlikely to get what you want. You should take the `alloc-init` approach.

**Using Associative References**

You will need to `#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>` for this to work.

To set,

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(button, "va", @"This is the string", OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

And to retrieve,

```
NSString * va = (NSString *)objc_getAssociatedObject(button, "va");
```

This way you wouldn't need to subclass `UIButton`.

Comment: Sure enough, that seemed to fix it! Thanks :D I'll let you know if I run into any problems with this method.

Comment: Hmmm. When I actually try to display my custom buttons on the view now, they don't show up. I'm guessing this is because the buttons don't have a "buttonType" property set. However, since buttonType is a readonly property, I can't set it using dot syntax. Is there anyway I can set the buttonType using the alloc-init approach?

Comment: No. You can't set it. Once you subclass it, it will default to `UIButtonStyleCustom`. You will have to define a frame, set the images or override its `drawRect` method.

Comment: Is there any other way to associate some variable (va) with a UIButton?

Comment: You can use [`associative references`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just extending UIControl...turned out to be alot easier :)

```
- (IBAction)setAndRetrieveVa:(id)sender{

TaskUIButton *newTaskButton = [[TaskUIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(29.0, (76.0+ (88*taskCounter)), 692, 80.0)];
[newTaskButton addTarget:self action:@selector(function1:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[newTaskButton addTarget:self action:@selector(function2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
[newTaskButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[newTaskButton setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newTaskButton setVa:@"please work!"];
NSLog(@"%@", newTaskButton.va);
}
```

And for click highlighting, I can always add a function that changes the background color when touch-down occurs, and switches the color back when touch-up occurs. Hurrah!